# React Native & Flatlist, array items not available (.length === 0)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm experience an issue in react native where when the array i have in my state is behaving very strangely. It says i have content in the array, but the array.length === 0. Here is a screenshot of my **chatrooms** array to show you what i mean (this is at the beginning of my FlatList component (receiving props.chatrooms array)

```
console.log('props.chatrooms')
console.log(props.chatrooms)
console.log(props.chatrooms.length)
```

[image]

I'm grabbing all the private and group chatIds, then making a call to those chatrooms to get the details of the users. Here is how i'm pulling the information:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            //? Refactor to pull userId from Redux Store
            let friendsArray = []
            let chatrooms = []
            let privateChatIds = []
            let groupChatIds = []
            AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(userId => {

                let currentUser = {}
                firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get().then(snapshot => {
                    currentUser = snapshot.data()
                }).then(() => this.setState({ currentUser: currentUser }))


                firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('friends').get().then((snapshot) => {
                    if (!snapshot.empty) {
                        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            friendsArray.push(doc.data())
                            privateChatIds.push(doc.data().chatroomId)
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Nothing to Grab')
                    }
                }).then(() => this.setState({ friends: friendsArray }))

                // get each array and put into the chatroomsArray

                firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('groupChatrooms').get().then((snapshot) => {
                    if (!snapshot.empty) {
                        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            groupChatIds.push(doc.data().key)
                        })
                    }
                    //! will want to limit this number to like 10-15 or something 
                }).then(() => {

                    for (let i = 0; i < privateChatIds.length; i++) {
                        firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('private').collection(privateChatIds[i]).doc('info').get().then((snapshot) => {
                            chatrooms.push(snapshot.data())
                        })
                    }

                    for (let i = 0; i < groupChatIds.length; i++) {
                        firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('group').collection(groupChatIds[i]).doc('info').get().then((snapshot) => {
                            chatrooms.push(snapshot.data())
                        })
                    }

                }).then(() => {

                    console.log('chatrooms')
                    console.log(chatrooms)
                    this.setState({ chatrooms, isLoading: false })
                })
            })
            
        })
    }
```

is my code perfect? no, probably pretty terrible performance-wise,  but i'm just trying to get it to work. I figure i'm resetting the chatrooms array or something, but why would it log as an array of items i want but then immediately after log as .length === 0??? Help!

Update: I'm seeing this content render from the flatlist initially and then it disappears

Comment: is chatroomsArray and props.chatrooms is same ? if yes have you tried logging `chatroomsArray` in the render function ?

Comment: chatrooms is the name of the prop in the flatlist, its receiving this.state.chatroomsArray (so its the same content)

Comment: and yes, i logged it in the render function, thats what the screenshot/console is giving back, when opened it shows items, but it looks like an empty array